# How to use eval instead if else in python

Tags: python

I have a global variable one, two, three ... and I have a variable "num" (it is a string) that can be "one" or "two" or "three" ...I want to do the next thing :

```
if num == "one":
   one = True
elif num=="two":
   two = True
elif num=="three":
   three = True
...
```

in perl I can do it with 1 line : something like eval "$num = True" instead of the long if else above. How can I do it in python ?

Comment: [Using eval is bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/1211429).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  I wouldn't be surprised if there's a simpler solution that avoids this whole wonky True/False thing.

Comment: You are almost certainly doing something the wrong way. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!`

Comment: I an sure that there is a better way to write this - but I am using code that others wrote so changing the way the variables are written is a mess. I am trying to do exactly what I wrote - have a variable string that has the exact name of an existing variable and I am trying to turn this existing variable to True if I have the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although most likely, there are [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000482/355230) to accomplish whatever it is for you're trying do, here's how:

```
one, two, three = False, False, False
print "before:", one, two, three  # before: False False False
num = "two"
eval("globals().update({%r: True})" % num)
print " after:", one, two, three  #  after: False True False
```

Comment: I know that there are better solution but I am looking for the solution that will not make me have to change others code. this is exactly what I was looking for ! thx.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `globals()` to access global names as a dictionary:

```
globals()[num] = True
```

but you normally want to keep your data out of your variable names. Use a dictionary instead of globals here instead:

```
numbers = {'one': False, 'two': False, 'three': False}

numbers[num] = True
```

or perhaps an object:

```
class Numbers:
    one = two = three = False

numbers = Numbers()

setattr(numbers, num, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eval is rather dangerous, so just like globals() I'm offering a slightly more eligant solution.

If you would want to build a dictionary with your keys being the "one", "two", etc... and the values being False.  Then all you need to do is:

```
if num in switch_dict:
    switch_dict[num] = True
```

Then to get meaningful data back all you need to do is

```
print switch_dict[num]
```

or for control flow

```
if switch_dict[num]:
    <do stuff>
```